# Can one genesis block have multiple network identifiers?

Tags: go-ethereum, genesis

Can one genesis block have multiple network identifiers?
I am new to Ethereum. So pardon me if it is a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's basically the definition of an identifier, it is unique.